# Is it possible to gain access to AWS resources by Amazon Social Login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on

I was requested to create an app that people login using their AWS credentials and the app does actions on AWS resources on their behalf.

Is this possible with oAuth flow, meaning that the users login on AWS and my app received an access token, or the only way to do this is by asking the user to enter his access/secret in my app?

Answer (score 0):

[Cognito with User pool and Identity pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html#scenario-identity-pool) is made for this use case.

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-identity-pools.html) is getting started guide. Here are the steps:

- Create a pool.
- [Integrate pool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkP2GB713rY) with identity provider.
- [Setup roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html) and necessary permissions.
- [Pass this token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html#getting-credentials-1.javascript) to get AWS Credentials.

Sample code to get aws credentials:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
    Logins: { // optional tokens, used for authenticated login
        'graph.facebook.com': 'FBTOKEN',
        'www.amazon.com': 'AMAZONTOKEN',
        'accounts.google.com': 'GOOGLETOKEN',
        'appleid.apple.com': 'APPLETOKEN'
    }
});

AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
    var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
    var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
    var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
});
```